# find a keyword in a string with python and regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I would like to find a keyword in a string that can be at the begining, the end, or anywhere in the string.

I started with something like that:

```
import re
my_keyword = "in ocean"
regex = r'[^|\,\s]?in ocean\,\s|[^|\,\s]?in ocean$'
```

**should match:**

```
in ocean there is big fish
in ocean
there is big fish in ocean
there is big fish in ocean but not in lakes
i like to swim in lake, in ocean too
in ocean, there is big fish
```

**should not match:**

```
within ocean, you can find tresure
in oceania there is sirens
tintin ocean, the tresure hunter
do not dive within ocean
```

Comment: @AmitJoki: clearly not; otherwise `in oceania` or `within ocean` would match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use word boundaries:

```
regex = r'\bin ocean\b'
```

A word boundary matches between a `\w` character and a `\W` character, or between a `\w` and a `^` or `$`.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/bZ5xJ3)

Comment: OMG! So simple, you saved my day. And thank you for the link, nice regex tester.